# How to pass data elements from HTML to code page Razor Components

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, progressive-web-apps

I have an opportunity at work to develop a new app.  I decided to tackle this using a PWA using Blazor.

I am using VS 2022 .NET 6.  I followed the MS example of creating a PWA.  I need to ask the user for a file location then pass that value to the code page to process it.  The value for the path and file name are coming across as null.  Where am I going wrong?

IndexPartialClass.razor.cs

```cs
using System.IO;
using ExcelDataReader;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace TRY2.Pages
{
    public partial class Index
    {
        private string txtFileName ="txtFileName" ;
        private object ShowMessage = "";
        public void ProcessFile()
        {
            using (var stream = File.Open(txtFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
                {
                    do
                    {
                        while (reader.Read()) //Each ROW
                        {
                            for (int column = 0; column < reader.FieldCount; column++)
                            {
                                ShowMessage = reader.GetValue(column).ToString();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Index.razor

```
@page "/"

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="lblPFile">Progyny File : </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="file" name="txtFileName" id="txtFileName" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<PageTitle>Progyny File Information</PageTitle>
<h1>Progyny File </h1>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="ProcessFile">Process File</button>
<p>
    <textarea> @ShowMessage </textarea>
</p>
```

Comment: You want to process the file on the client? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=server) or from a web server request?

Comment: You have compilation error in your C#. Please check syntax around `do { ... }`. It should be either `do { ... } while (reader.Read())` OR `whle (reader.Read()) { ... }`.